# the degree of the discriminant of a cubic irreducibble polynomial over the rational adjoint a root

Tags: extension-field, discriminant

Let $f(x) \in \mathbb Q[x]$ and $$f(x)= x^3 + px +q=(x-r_1)(x-r_2)(x-r_3),$$  and $r_1, r_2,r_3\in K$ for the splitting field $K$ of $f(x)$.
Let the $D = (r_3 - r_1)^2(r_2- r_1)^2(r_3 - r_2)^2$, which is the discriminant of $f(x)$.
The square root of the discriminant $D$ is clearly in the splitting field because $\sqrt D= |(r_3 - r_1)(r_2- r_1)(r_3 - r_2)|$.

How to find
$[\mathbb Q(r_1)(\sqrt{D}):\mathbb Q]$, i.e. the degree of the extension field of $\mathbb Q$ adjoining $\sqrt D$ and $r_1$?

I tried to find the degree of $\sqrt D$ over $\mathbb Q(r_1)$ and did not find the minimal polynomial of it. The degree is surely at most $2$. It is just not clear to me whether it is $1$ or $2$, or it depends on $f(x)$.

related: [Splitting field of a degree 3 polynomial is generated by a root and the square root of the discriminant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4607168/1258470)
Since proposition points out this extension field is simply the splitting field of $f(x)$ over $\Bbb Q$.

In short, my question:

- what is the degree of $\sqrt D$ (over $\Bbb Q(r_1)$ and $\Bbb Q$) ? What are all possibilities and what condition does these depend on?
- Equivalently, what is the degree of the splitting field (which is equal to $\Bbb Q(r_1)(\sqrt D)$ according to the linked question) of $f(x)$ given its discriminant? (Is there even relations between them?)

Comment: Are you familiar with the expression for $D$ in terms of $p$ and $q$? When that expression is a perfect square, then of course $\sqrt D$ is an integer, so it's of degree one over the rationals. Otherwise, degree two. The degree one case is called a *cyclic cubic*.

Comment: Yes. I know that $D=-27q^2 -4p^3$.

Comment: I came up with the following: $[\Bbb Q(r)(\sqrt D) : \Bbb Q(r)]$ is either $1$ or $2$. When  $D$ is not a square, so $\sqrt D \not\in \Bbb Q$, I claim $$[\Bbb Q(r)(\sqrt D) : \Bbb Q(r)] =2$$. Because if it is equal to $1$, then $\sqrt D \in \Bbb Q(r)$ meaning $Q(\sqrt D)$ is a subfield of $\Bbb Q(r)$, hence $3 = [\Bbb Q(r) : \Bbb Q] = [\Bbb Q(r): \Bbb Q(\sqrt D)][\Bbb Q(\sqrt D) : \Bbb Q]$. This would imply $2\mid 3$ a contradiction, from where I conclude $[\Bbb Q (r)(\sqrt D):B(r)] = 6$ if $\sqrt D \not\in \Bbb Q$.

Comment: OK. You ask, "what condition does these [sic] depend on?" The condition it depends on is whether $-27q^2-4p^3$ is a square.

Comment: I was actually a bit confused on this point.   Now I get it. "If this expression is a perfect square, then of course $\sqrt D$ is an integer". I wondered for a while if it would be valid to say "D is a square in $\Bbb Q$. "without pointing out that $D$ is expressed using coefficients in $\Bbb Q$. Perhaps this is because I need to know that $D$ is in $\Bbb Q$ in the first place, before I can assume that it is or is not a square in $\Bbb Q$...

Comment: If Galois Theory is in your toolbox, then $D$ is rational because it is invariant under all elements of the Galois group of the splitting field. If you don't have Galois Theory, it's a little hard to explain, but, very loosely, the idea is that any bijection $\sigma$ from the splitting field to itself that preserves the field operations must act as a permutation on the roots of $f$, from which it follows that $\sigma(D)=D$; but the only elements of the splitting field that are fixed by all the operation-preserving bijections of the splitting field are the rationals.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The degree of $\sqrt D$ over the rationals is one if $D=-27q^2-4p^3$ is a square, two otherwise. The degree of the splitting field is three if $D$ is a square, six otherwise.

The full story is best explained via Galois Theory, which is a bit of a long story. Copying from my comment on the question,

"very loosely, the idea is that any bijection $\sigma$ from the splitting field to itself that preserves the field operations must act as a permutation on the roots of $f$, from which it follows that $\sigma(D)=D$; but the only elements of the splitting field that are fixed by all the operation-preserving bijections of the splitting field are the rationals."